# Possible to create tilted column labels with CSS?

Tags: css, rotation, label

Is it possible to create vertical or slanted column labels on the columns of a table, using CSS?

[image: Sample table with fake data]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rotate text and elements using [CSS3 transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms):

```
th[scope="col"] {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
```

Having nothing better to do, I put together a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/bRDmK/7) mimicking your entire table (**EDIT:** now with borders!).

Comment: You should add `-ms-transform` for IE9. Let's just pretend IE7/8 don't exist.

Comment: @thirtydot: Done. Also I finally added borders.

Comment: @thirtydot: Aaaaaaaaaaargh IE9 doesn't render the top left corner properly. Curse you Microsoft!!!

Comment: @thirtydot: Thanks - I knew how to fix it but got lazy. It's IE, after all.

Comment: @thirtydot - "Let's pretend IE doesn't exist." Fixed it for you.